# Ice Water Content from GFS file

Tags: meteorology, clouds, weather-forecasting, gfs, cloud-microphysics

I am working my way through this paper: http://downloads.hindawi.com/journals/amete/2017/8707234.pdf

Equations 10 and 11 require the ice water content.  I can't find it in the GFS grib2 file variables.  Did I miss it, or is possible to derive it from the available information.  Right now I have pressure, temperature, and relative humidity.

Answer (score 1):

There is a parameter `ice water mixing ratio` in the `gfs.t<hour>z.pgrb2.0p25.f<step>` file given at isobaric levels.

Comment: To get the IWC, I would multiple by the density of dry air?